# Importing data from open api and using a loop combined with a mysql loop

Tags: php, mysql, swagger

I'm using an openapi json source that includes id:s that I could possibly convert to a human readable format by using a database in mysql containing the same id:s and a matching names to those id:s.

Openapi communication is handled by a composer package from where it is easy enough to just `foreach` through the array that then shows all the id's currently in use.

Then I can't figure out a solution to get that mysql part right to transfer all of the id:s for a name, i have thought and tried some double loops but they havent worked.  `while` inside a `foreach` and the other way around.

Separately I can get things to work out but not combined.

```
$sql = "SELECT activityName, activityID FROM Activities";
$sqlresult = $conn_->query($sql);
if ($sqlresult->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $sqlresult->fetch_assoc()){
                foreach($_jobs as $obj)
                        {
                            echo $obj->activity_id . " Type id: " . $obj->origin_type_id . " Status: " . $obj->status . "<br>";
                        }
}} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo json_last_error() . PHP_EOL . "<br>";
echo json_last_error_msg() . PHP_EOL . "<br>";

$conn->close();
```

Currently it just echoes them openapi results 10 times as is the amount of rows in the mysql database.

```
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
5 type id: 1115 Status: active
4 type id: 11891 Status: active
4 type id: 11890 Status: active
```

I want to be able to use that openapi `activity_id` to fetch a matching name from the mysql database. Can i maybe put the loops other way around with no errors? Or is the approach wrong all together?

Comment: Hi Magezilla, Posting the non working parts of your code will help you to get relevant answers. Unfortunately no will be able to help you just with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the code doesn't seem to make any attempt to print the database details. However what it does do, due to the nested loops, is print all the API data again for each database row returned.

You need to separate these two things. First get all the database data out into an associative array. Make the key of the array the activity ID. That way, when you come to print the API data and combine it with the database data, you can simply use the activity ID to reference the correct item in the associative array.

This should do the job (untested):

```
$activities = array();
$sql = "SELECT activityName, activityID FROM Activities";
$sqlresult = $conn_->query($sql);

if ($sqlresult->num_rows > 0) 
{
  while($row = $sqlresult->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $activities[$row["activityID"]] = $row["activityName"];
  }

  foreach($_jobs as $obj)
  {
    echo $obj->activity_id . " Type id: " . $obj->origin_type_id . " Status: " . $obj->status . " Name: ". $activities[$obj->activity_id] . "<br>";
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: This worked good, i have only worked with joins in mysql, next i was trying to figure out how to import json to mysql momentarily to do them joins but this came in first, somehow feels wrong that you cant directly work with both types simultaneously.